# Rails 4, Bootstrap - CSS to have content displayed in columns

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have a list of industries (which is dynamic).

I want users to check box click which industry they are in.

At the moment, that displays in one single long list.

I want the list to be spread across columns so that the whitespace is used.

How do I turn this list output, into something that displays as a list of options across 3 columns?

```
                    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <%= f.association :industries,
                     as: :check_boxes,
                     label_method: :sector,
                     value_method: :id,
                     label: 'Select your industries (up to 3)' %>
<!--                      fix formatting so it spreads across columns -->
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="column">
  <%= f.association :industries,
         as: :check_boxes,
         label_method: :sector,
         value_method: :id,
         label: 'Select your industries' %>
</div>

<style>
#columns {
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 20px;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 20px;
} </style>
```

Comment: Hi Nirajan - I pasted the wrong bit of code first time around. I changed it to the current form input I'm using

Comment: If your code is working just fine and you only want to style it into 3 columns then , make a div with styling as I have mentioned above and place your code within this new div

Comment: I'm afraid i don't understand your code. Thanks anyway. I'm using bootstrap and simple form for this. I'm not sure how to make your idea fit in with these tools.

Comment: check the new answer!

Comment: I've tried it, but it puts the label into one of the columns. I'll fix it by splitting the label out into a separate form field. Thanks for this so far- it's better than what I could get ti to do